# Is there a way to disable Facetime from starting?

Tags: startup, facetime

I don't use facetime. I'd like to disable it so it doesn't automatically start following system startup. Is there a way to do this? (MacBook Pro, High Sierra)

Comment: Look in: System Preferences > Users & Groups > (select you) > Login Items. If Facetime is shown in the list of login items, remove it by unlocking the pane if necessary, selecting Facetime in the login list, then pressing the "-" button below the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to: System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Login Items.

On this screen you can choose which programs will open automatically upon startup. You can remove FaceTime from this list to disable it opening on startup.

You can also add any programs you would actually like to start when you boot up.

[image: Click the lock, Facetime, and then the minus symbol.]

Comment: Mine is not in the list and it's still starting. And it's not checked as `Open at Login`

Comment: Same problem.  It's not listed and still starts up whenever I boot.  How do I know, because it keeps nagging me to update and change my password.  Damn, I've had adware that's less annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I found this way to keep Facetime from running at startup.  Since it's a rather insidious program, you have to take much more drastic steps to force this program to play nicely.

There is a `.plist` file that can cause Facetime to run during startup.  Delete that file, and it should no longer start automatically.  It should still run normally if you want (by clicking on the app icon in the Applications folder).

The file can be found at:

`/Users/[account_name]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.facetime.plist`

...where [account_name] is your user name.  The easiest way to find it is through terminal as the Library/ directory is usually hidden in the graphical interfaces (Finder).

Just delete that file and reboot.  I'm pretty sure nothing important is stored in that file, other than "run me during startup!"

Tested on High Sierra.

Comment: This is the way to go! On Monterey I removed the files below and no more annoyance from an app I never want to use. com.apple.facetime.bag.plist
com.apple.messages.facetime.plist